# Why is there a one hour difference between two time_t values when converting to tm struct and back?

Tags: c, linux, utc, mktime

When I execute the following code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  time_t rawtime = 0;
  time_t secs;
  struct tm* timeinfo = gmtime(&rawtime);

  printf("rawtime : %s\n", asctime(timeinfo));

  secs = mktime(timeinfo);

  printf("converted time : %s\n", asctime(gmtime(&secs)));

  return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
rawtime : Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
converted time : Wed Dec 31 23:00:00 1969
```

Why is this one hour difference?

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 64bit btw.

Comment: Because you live one hour away from Greenwich ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because mktime converts a local time, not a system time (gmtime), into a timestamp.

Comment: You could probably use the nonstandard function `timegm` to do what you want.